# display confirmation message after a button click inside update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

In my page, I have 3 update panels. each of them have a save button. I need to show a confirmation message after the system saves data successfully. The message must show and fade out after 5 seconds.

I have a DIV and inside that I have a label on which I am writing the confirmation text from code behind. I am showing and fading out the DIV with jquery.

BUT the problem is, if I put the confirmation DIV out side the update panel, the label dont show up.
If I put the confirmation DIV inside the update panel, jquery function does not work properly. I mean the DIV shows up and fading does not work.

Any help guys??

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make jquery workable inside an update-panel you need this, let me know if this helps...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function jqueryEnabled() {
   your jquery method
}

</script>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.Application.add_load(jqueryEnabled);
</script>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Man, you are too cool. Thanks it works. If I place the Confirmation DIV inside the update panel, the jquery works now. BUT as I have 3 update panels and save button in each of them, is there any way that I show the same Confirmation DIV and Label for every button??

Comment: no cool man faced similar problems year back...thanks for the kind words..i think the same jquery function will do it for you just change the internal html based on your specific button.